# Final variable in Switch case. Error: Constant expression required

Tags: java, switch-statement, constants, final

I know that there is a few similar questions on SO but I really didn't get my answer from those I can find.

I wonder why this first example is WORKING but the second example is NOT.

```
public class Person
{
    private final String FIRST_NAME = "Harley";
    private final String LAST_NAME  = "Davidson";

    public void display()
    {
        switch ("Harley")
        {
            case FIRST_NAME:
                System.out.println(FIRST_NAME);
                break;
            case LAST_NAME:
                System.out.println(LAST_NAME);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In this one I'm passing those String variables as arguments. In method declaration I use final modifier as well but still I get the `Constant expression required` error.

```
public class Person
{
    public void display(final String fName, final String lName)
    {
        switch ("Harley")
        {
            case fName:
                System.out.println(fName);
                break;
            case lName:
                System.out.println(lName);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The cases in a switch statement need to be compile-time constant. In your second example, they are function parameters, so they are unknown until runtime. (Maybe you only ever call it with the same two values, but the compiler is considering the context of the method, not of the entire program.)

Comment: The second example isn't working because you can pass anything into you're display method and a switch statement cannot be generated dynamically on the fly. Just think about what would actually happen if you called `display("test", "test")` or `display(null, null)`

Comment: I see. Thank you both for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Constant means a constant at compile time, not at runtime.

The compiler is smart enough to work out, at compile time, that your first example is *always* constant. So it substitutes in a constant at compile time. The switch's cases are always constant.

As far as that second example is concerned though, you are trying to do a switch with dynamic cases. Theoretically you could call that second example with different parameters - so it resolves them at runtime rather than compile time. That is why it shows you that error, as switches don't like runtime level variables as cases (even if they turn out always to be constant).

Answer (score 0):

Look up the definition of "constant" in the JLS. It's not the same as a `final` variable.